Ratio of l1/l2 norm over n dimensional vector
According to here
$$\frac{(|c_1|+|c_2|+\cdots+|c_n|)^2}{c_1^2+c_2^2+\cdots+c_n^2}\geq 1$$
The equality holds when for each $i\neq j\in[n]$, $|c_i||c_j|=0$.
Could we improve the lower bound by considering a vector $\vec c$ which elements are all non-zero? Specifically,
$$\forall i\in[n],c_i\in\{-1,-1+\epsilon,-1+2\epsilon,-1+3\epsilon,\cdots,-1+(m-1)\epsilon\}$$
where $m:=\lfloor\epsilon^{-1}+1\rfloor$ is an integer. Namely, $c$ is a vector only takes value on the equally spaced discrete points in the cube $[-1,0)^n$. Each dimension of the cube is discretize into $m$ equal sub-intervals, and there are $m$ discrete points on each dimension.
In this case, what would be the lower bound of $\frac{\|\vec c\|_1^2}{\|\vec c\|_2^2}$?
What I tried
$$\frac{(|c_1|+|c_2|+\cdots+|c_n|)^2}{c_1^2+c_2^2+\cdots+c_n^2}=\frac{c_1^2+c_2^2+\cdots+c_n^2+2\sum_{i<j}c_ic_j}{c_1^2+c_2^2+\cdots+c_n^2}=1+\frac{2\sum_{i<j}c_ic_j}{c_1^2+c_2^2+\cdots+c_n^2}$$
If $n=2$ then $\frac{c_1c_2}{c_1^2+c_2^2}$ takes minimum at $c_1=-1+(m-1)\epsilon$ or $c_2=-1+(m-1)\epsilon$.
However, I have no idea how to deal with higher dimension case.
Update:
As pointed out Lemma 3.3 in the paper gives a lower bound $\frac{\|x\|_1^2}{\|x\|_2^2}\geq(\frac{2\sqrt{U}}{1+U})^2\|x\|_0$ where $U=\frac{\min_{S(x)}x_i}{\max_{S(x)}x_i}$ and $\|x\|_0$ is the number of nonzero in vector $x$.
I am a bit confused: assume all $c_i\geq 0$ and there are $N$ nonzero elements $c_1,\cdots,c_N$, then$$\frac{\|c\|_1^2}{\|c\|_2^2}=\frac{(c_1+\cdots+c_N)^2}{c_1^2+\cdots+c_N^2}\geq \frac{(N\cdot\min(c_1,\cdots,c_N))^2}{N\cdot(\max(c_1,\cdots,c_N))^2}=N\cdot\Big(\frac{\min}{\max}\Big)^2=N\cdot U^2$$ I think this bound should be quite loose.
In addition, from the paper, $$\frac{\|c\|_1^2}{\|c\|_2^2}\geq \Big(\frac{2\sqrt{U}}{1+U}\Big)^2 \cdot N$$
Then it should be $$U^2\leq\Big(\frac{2\sqrt{U}}{1+U}\Big)^2$$ but it's not.

I think this is what you need: https://www.math.uci.edu/~jxin/CIS-14-YEX.pdf. Check Lemma 3.2 and Lemma 3.3

@greyls Thank you! I will have to check carefully whether they have additional assumption on vector $x$

@greyls I have an update in my post

are you sure that inequality does not hold? It seems to me that all ok for $0<U\le 1$

@greyls yes if $0<U\leq 1$ then the bound in the paper is coarser than the bound $U^2$. But if $U>1$ then the bound in the paper is tighter, right?

For your problem $U\le 1$. Moreover the ratio $||x||_1/||x||_2$ is scale-invariant. That's without loss of generality we can assume that $\max x_i=1$. Check text between Theorem 3.2 and Lemma 3.2 in paper.

@greyls oh I see! but then, actually the bound in the paper is looser than $U^2$, this is a bit strange..

why this bound is looser if $U^2\le \left( \frac{2\sqrt{U}}{1+U} \right)^2$?
